# upload image error in mobile and success in web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, axios

In resume, when sendo image by web I receive success. When sendo image by mobile I don't receive success.
"react": "^18.0.0",
"react-dropzone": "^14.2.3",

My error:
`column: 12` 
`line: 17915` 
`message: "Right side of assignment cannot be destructured"`
`sourceURL: "http://192.xxx.1.x:3001/static/js/bundle.js"`
`stack: "@http://192.xxx.1.x:3001/static/js/bundle.js:17915:12"`

My data is equal in web and mobile.

My drop zone:

```
  const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isFocused, isDragAccept, isDragReject } =
    useDropzone({
      accept: [
        '.txt',
        '.rtf',
        '.doc',
        '.docx',
        '.jpg',
        '.jpeg',
        '.png',
        '.gif',
        '.heic',
        '.heif',
      ],
      onDrop: handleDrop,
      maxSize: 15728640,
    });
```

My func at front:

```
  const handleSave = async () => {
    if (images.length === 0) return;

    setIsLoading(true);
    const aux = [];
    try {
      const promisseImages = images.map(async img => {
        if (img.file) {
          const res = await addNewImage(img);
          await Promise.all(res);
          return { name: img.label, file: res.url };
        } 
      });
      const resultImages = await Promise.all(promisseImages);
      aux.push(...resultImages);
      await dispatch(updateAttendanceAttachments(attendanceId, aux));
    } catch (error) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      console.error('# Erro ao adicionar imagem:', error);
      throw error; 
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
    setSend(true);
  };
```

and

```
export const addNewImage = async data => {
  try {
    dispatch(RegisterProfessionalSlice.actions.startLoading());
    // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-const
    let bodyFormData = new FormData();
    bodyFormData.append('file', data.file, '_');
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    };
    
    const response = await axios.postForm(
      `/upload/upload`,
      bodyFormData,
      config
    );

    dispatch(RegisterProfessionalSlice.actions.uploadSuccess(response.data));
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(RegisterProfessionalSlice.actions.hasError(error));
  }
};
```

My controller at backend:

```
@Controller('upload')
@ApiTags('upload')
export class UploadController {
    constructor(private service: UploadService) { }

    @Post('upload')
    @ApiConsumes('multipart/form-data')
    @ApiOperation({ summary: 'Realiza o upload de um arquivo no S3' })
    @ApiOkResponse({ type: ResponseUploadDto })
    @ApiBody({
        schema: {
            type: 'object',
            properties: {
                file: {
                    type: 'string',
                    format: 'binary',
                },
            },
        },
    })

    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file', {
        storage: memoryStorage()
    }))
    @ApiBearerAuth()
    @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
    async uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file?: Express.Multer.File, @Request() req?): Promise<any> {
        const result = await this.service.uploadPublicFile(
            file.buffer,
            file.originalname,
        );
        return result;
    }

}
```

repeat, same func I get success in web but don't have success at mobile.